# Understanding Neo4j server plugins

Tags: java, neo4j

I'm in the early stages of learning how to use Neo4J, and have just begin experimenting with the Neo4J REST server. In particular, I'm interested in creating server plugins, but the [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/server-plugins.html) here has left me with quite a few questions. Firstly:

They give  the following example:

```
@Description( "An extension to the Neo4j Server for getting all nodes or relationships")
public class GetAll extends ServerPlugin {
    @Name( "get_all_nodes" )
    @Description( "Get all nodes from the Neo4j graph database" )
    @PluginTarget( GraphDatabaseService.class )
    public Iterable<Node> getAllNodes( @Source GraphDatabaseService graphDb )....{
```

and say:

```
Make sure that the discovery point type in the @PluginTarget and the @Source parameter   
are of the same type.
```

- a) What is a *discovery point* ?
- b) What do the `@PluginTarget` and `@Source` annotations designate, and what should they point to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@PluginTarget` decides if your server plugin enriches the existing REST interface on the context of nodes, relationships or on database level, so it's the anchor point.

The `@Source` annotation is used to pass in the respective context as a parameter into your application.

Take a look at [the example](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-plugins.html). The `getAllNodes` extension acts on global context whereas `shortestPath` is based on a node.